# IF statement with multiple AND operators

Tags: python

I've got the following line in my code, which works well, but it looks very ugly.

```
if not line.startswith("<ul>") and not line.startswith("<ol>") and not line.startswith("<li>"):
```

Is there a better way to write this line?

Thanks

Comment: `if not any(line.startswith(i) for i in ('<ul>', '<ol>', '<li>'))`

Comment: That's one way, but I honestly wouldn't worry about it.  Your conditional reads pretty easily, which is what's important

Comment: Since the tags are all the same length, you can also just do: `if not line[:4] in ('<ul>', '<ol>', '<li>')`.

Comment: @RickTeachey that's a very brittle method, you need to know that all the strings you're checking are 4 characters and ensure any changes meet the same constraint.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah. That's what I said. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any` with a list comprehension or generator:

```
if not any(line.startswith(tag) for tag in ['<ul>', '<ol>', '<li>']):
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression

```
import re

if not re.match("^<ol>|^<ul>|^<li>", line):
```

Comment: My regex skills may be rusty but the second is not equivalent to the first one, and wrong for the requirement : '<ll>' will match but not '<li>'.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @polku

Answer (score 0):

Use `any()` it return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

```
if not any(line.startswith(x) for x in ["<ul>", "<ol>", "<li>"]):
```

Answer (score 0):

Needless to say there are multiple ways to do this (as with anything in coding). But if you're planning on using these tags later again, another way to do it would be to create a list that holds those tags, then reference that list whenever you need to.
I.e.

```
tags = ["<ul>", "<ol>", "<li>"]
#your code here
if line.startswith not in tags:
    #your code here
```